# Apex : How to generate modal page URL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following code that generates a normal APEX page URL :

```
PageURL := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || AppId || ':' || PageAlias || ':' || SessionId ||'::NO::' || Arguments || ':' || ArgumentValues, p_checksum_type => Checksum);
```

How can I generate a URL for a modal page? I am on version 18.2.0.00.1.

Comment: As far as I know it is the same function. APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL returns the correct URL for modal or non modal pages. In the first case, for modal pages, that function will return a javascript function. But you can use in a href attribute without any problem.

Comment: You can use `apex_util.prepare_url` but a simpler method is to use `apex_page.get_url` instead - that way you don't need to worry about url syntax at all.